# Update MySQL using decoded json array as ids column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, ajax

- I've passed an array to my PHP script with AJAX and decoded the array in PHP using json_decode().
- I'm now trying to use a foreach loop to fetch each value from the array, then use it to reference the correct id in my database table, and finally to update the values in the "archived" column in the database for that same row to '1'.
- I am getting an Error each time I try to update the database.

The $_POST data looks like this:

```
(
    [data] => ["1","2","3","4"]
)
```

and the decoded array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

where each value represents the id of a row I would like to update in the MySQL table.

Here is my PHP script:

```
<?php

//Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);

$username="username";
$password="password";
$database="tgpgigs";

//Connect to database
$conn = new mysqli(localhost, $username, $password, $database);

//Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
echo "Connected to db";
}

//OUTPUT POST DATA
$array = $_POST['data'];

//CHECK DATA
$deData = json_decode($array);
print_r($deData);

//UPDATE MySQL
foreach($deData as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
    $upSQL = "UPDATE gigdata SET archived='1' WHERE id='".$value."'";
}
```

At present, the foreach loop is echoing each $value correctly, but no joy in updating them in the database. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your foreach cycle like this:

```
foreach($deData as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
    $upSQL = "UPDATE gigdata SET archived='1' WHERE id='".$value."'";
    $conn->query($upSQL);
}
```

I hope that may help you.

Comment: I've been on that for hours... :(

Thank you!